# Definition of "overhead"

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-models

I am writing a paper on the invariance thesis introduced by Cees F. Slot and Peter van Emde Boas as;

> 'Reasonable' machines can simulate each other within a polynomially bounded overhead in time and a constant-factor overhead in space.

The paper I am writing is in Croatian where I cannot find a properly convenient word like "overhead". Also, I am unable to find a strict Computer Science definition for the term.

Specifically, I have $Time(M)$ as the cost of reducing the $\lambda$-term $M$ to its normal form and a Turing machine able to simulate this reduction in $O((Time(M))^4)$. Therefore, I would like to say  "this TM can simulate $\lambda$-calculus with polynomial-time [overhead]" concisely as it is in English.

I would appreciate any suggestion in the form of literature references for the definition, advice on how to best define it myself or even synonyms of the word.

Comment: Can this [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_(computing)) help you a little bit?

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion also gives me an idea to narrow my question. It is not that I'm unsure what overhead is, but the problem I have is how to say it concisely in Croatian. I may have to define a new word in my paper or just use "overhead", but I will wait for more suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure that "how do I phrase this concisely in Croatian?" is on-topic here.

Comment: You are right and I am not asking that. I am asking for various definitions or possible synonyms for overhead to help me with phrasing it. Because, where else could I find a group of people capable of correctly rephrasing polynomial-time overhead when simulating computation machines.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that “overhead” is a term. Here’s what we use in Russian papers:

1. оверхед — direct transliteration (for informal texts)
2. издержки — costs (of production)
3. Translations of “slowdown” (for time) and “blow-up” (for space).